# Flutter warning: path_provider_linux-0.0.1+1\android does not exist

Tags: android, flutter, upgrade

Running a Flutter project and after upgrading Android Studio to version **4.0** I get the following warning when opening the Android module in Android Studio:

```
Warning: root project 'android': Unable to resolve additional project configuration.
Details: org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Basedir C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-0.0.1+1\android does not exist.
```

I can see that now this android directory does indeed not exist.
On the project screen, it says: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.
I have tried to reinstall both Android Studio and Flutter, but it doesn't help.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: This happened to me when updating to Android Studio 4.1 Beta 1, going back to the previous version I used (4.0 Beta 5) appears to work

Answer (score 0):

in path_provider_linux & path_provider_macos no android project 
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_linux
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_macos

Comment: Thank you. It tried this, but it din not work, and I got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

In the pubspec.yaml file under dependencies use:

```
path_provider: ^1.6.5
```

Dont use latest one

In build.gradle make sure classpath is as follow:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties file makes sure this is the distribtion URL:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Make sure in all the gradle files the latest version are there.Android studio only will help that and try again